# Interspeech template breaks biblatex

Tags: biblatex

I am experiencing a weird issue while trying to write a paper using INTERSPEECH 2023 template (available from [here](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/interspeech-2023-paper-kit/kzcdqdmkqvbr)). It normally uses `bibtex` to generate the bibliography but as far as I know that does not support an operation similar to

```
\AtEveryBibitem{\clearlist{language}}
\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{note}}
```

that is available when one uses `biblatex`. For this reason I tried to switch to `biblatex` but this causes the following errors:

```
]
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \relax 
l.119 
      
A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.
(If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
look up `weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)

! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
<to be read again> 
                   \relax 
l.119 
      
Dimensions can be in units of em, ex, in, pt, pc,
cm, mm, dd, cc, nd, nc, bp, or sp; but yours is a new one!
I'll assume that you meant to say pt, for printer's points.
To recover gracefully from this error, it's best to
delete the erroneous units; e.g., type `2' to delete
two letters. (See Chapter 27 of The TeXbook.)

! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   }
l.119 
      
A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.
(If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
look up `weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)

! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
<to be read again> 
                   }
l.119
```

Few things I have already tried:

- Line 119 at main.tex basically contains the \printbibliography command. When I replace `INTERSPEECH2023.sty` the issue goes away.
- When I seach `INTERSPEECH2023.sty` for terms like 'bibliography', 'references', 'citation' etc. there is a single segment I could found and modifying that did not help with anything.
- If the error message was only a bit longer (if it gave the slight before of the context) then I suppose I could debug and solve but I could not really get anything from this much message. If there are any tips to make the log output more verbose I would also appreciate that.

MWE:

(you need the `INTERSPEECH2023.sty' from the overleaf [project](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/interspeech-2023-paper-kit/kzcdqdmkqvbr))

```
% main.tex

\documentclass{INTERSPEECH2023}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{comment}

\usepackage[
backend=biber,
style=alphabetic,
sorting=ynt
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{mybib.bib}

\title{Bibliography management: \texttt{biblatex} package}
\name{Overleaf}
\date{ }

\begin{document}

\maketitle

Using \texttt{biblatex} you can display bibliography divided into sections, 
depending of citation type. 
Let's cite! The Einstein's journal paper \cite{einstein}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}


% mybib.bib

@article{einstein,
  author =       "Albert Einstein",
  title =        "{Zur Elektrodynamik bewegter K{\"o}rper}. ({German})
                 [{On} the electrodynamics of moving bodies]",
  journal =      "Annalen der Physik",
  volume =       "322",
  number =       "10",
  pages =        "891--921",
  year =         "1905",
  DOI =          "http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/andp.19053221004",
  keywords =     "physics"
}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: @Mensch thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally speaking the only good reason to use a conference template is when you want to submit your work to that conference. If you want to do that you should usually not change the citation and bibliography setup: You should not switch the document to `biblatex` (even if that works without error) and you should not select a different style (BibTeX and `biblatex` styles are incompatible and there is no one-to-one replacement for most styles, so this is almost inevitable).

The error you get in your document is caused by the fact that the class redefines the sectioning commands `\section` and friends in a way that they no longer have a starred variant (`\section*`). By default `biblatex` typesets the heading with the starred `\section*`, which errors here.

You can force a numbered heading as follows

```
\printbibliography[heading=bibnumbered]
```

With this change the document compiled for me.

But as I said, I don't think you should try to use `biblatex` here. Stick with the style the template uses and get rid of the undesired fields in your `.bib` file with a tool like JabRef.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. In my case, I am not going to submit to this conference but instead I will be submitting to a satellite workshop of it (not going to be included in the proceedings etc.). So I think making minor changes as this one should not cause any problems.